# .NET Core project not opening, complaining about WPF and other unrelated stuff

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have a .NET Core project, that is OK on the PC of all developers, but on the PC of one developer, It complains that:

[image]

Can anyone please help me on this issue? I have nothing to do with .NET Framework and Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

This means the developer hasn't installed the .NET desktop development features on their instance of Visual Studio.

On that machine, launch the Visual Studio installer, and include the desktop development.

This is likely because of the `UserPanel.csproj` project either targets a specific target framework moniker (TFM) or because you are referencing components for relying on a specific target.

Can you share a snippet of the project file itself?